# How to get way ids from the OSRM map matching service

Tags: openstreetmap, line, open-source-routing-machine, map-matching

Calling [OSRM map matching](https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/8.610048,46.99917;8.620048,46.99917?overview=simplified&generate_hints=false&annotations=nodes&radiuses=50;50&geometries=geojson) returns `coordinates` and `nodes`:

> {"code":"Ok","matchings":[{"confidence":0.000854076,"geometry":{"coordinates":[[8.610984,46.998978],[8.61309,47.000206],[8.613144,47.000283],[8.613134,47.000372],[8.613506,47.000469],[8.613833,47.000622],[8.615571,47.001608],[8.616024,47.0013],[8.616167,47.000626],[8.616434,47.000464],[8.616554,47.000444],[8.617017,47.000525],[8.617696,47.000288],[8.620298,46.999676]],"type":"LineString"},"legs":[{"steps":[],"summary":"","weight":117.6,"duration":117.6,"annotation":{"nodes":[384845483,3831831361,2628299968,502266756,346268605,373873712,1302513709,9444444740,2431858827,10287564212,271979126,10721097610,10287564276,10721097609,10721097608,7328319500,7328319511,10287564277,271979123,9441944872,271979114,4560271019,373878694,4560271018,373878690,9442435560,373878688,9053978499,9442435552,9442435679,373878684,1085916739,373880925,9442435755,1085916895,373880928,1085916901,373880931,5753185380,373880934,4244175765,2431858826,433073515,373880937]},"distance":927.4}],"weight_name":"routability","weight":117.6,"duration":117.6,"distance":927.4}],"tracepoints":[{"alternatives_count":0,"waypoint_index":0,"matchings_index":0,"distance":74.351292817,"name":"Alte Kantonsstrasse","location":[8.610984,46.998978]},{"alternatives_count":5,"waypoint_index":1,"matchings_index":0,"distance":59.381641586,"name":"Schönenbuchstrasse","location":[8.620298,46.999676]}]}

The `coordinates` could be drawn as a series of lines on the map...

[image: map screenshot]

But I need the OSM `way` object ids, how to get them please?

There is no option listed in [the OSRM match service doc](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#match-service) to make it return way ids.

Does OSRM even have any *way* data? My newbie impression is that it only cares about OSM *nodes*, i.e. looks at their probabilities, using the HMM.

Comment: There are a few approaches outline here https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/5202 which will require some technical steps. I hope they will help you!

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that Github issue already... but my impression is that it would return the OSM *relation* object ids (like street ids), while I need *way* ids (segments of a street). Also from further reading I have the impression that OSRM operates with nodes (looks at probabilities and HMM...) and does not care about ways at all (maybe does not even have that information).

Comment: The nodes osrm uses were once part of ways. So it should work I guess. You  could also take the node ids which it returns for a map matched route and join them in the db to resolve the ways maybe?

Comment: Yes, that is actually my plan - to run 2 docker images: osrm-backend and postgis, and pass the nodes returned by OSRM map matching to the postgis SQL query to find the way ids (which contain at least 2 nodes of the list)...